# How can I build a Crew Station inside a building in my Outpost?

Tags: starfield

I would like to assign one of my crew members to my first Outpost. I know that I have to build a Crew Station first to do that.

But how can I build such a Crew Station (looks like an ordinary office desk) **inside** a building? Whatever I try, it results in a Crew Station on top of a building or anywhere outside.

After pressing the <kbd>E</kbd> button on my Beacon, I see the building menu. I can't find a way to place the Crew Station **inside** an existing building. Is there any way to open the build-menu inside a room?

What exactly do I have to do to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is for PC version:

Make sure you have placed an airlock attached to a habitat of some    kind.

Once inside the habitat, press **F** to enter **Survey mode**.
Once in Survey mode, enter **Build mode** by pressing **R**.

You can then start placing items indoors.

Happy decorating.

Comment: Note, this is the same actions you would need to do if you wanted to decorate a house you may have purchased.

Comment: Same actions for all platforms yeah.

Comment: It's just a small visible difference between the active and choosable "Build mode" with `R` in Scanner-Mode and the usual "not available" one. And decorating becomes tricky, because it's nearly impossible to place something exactly on a table or put a chair directly to a wall.